# How to allow check just single value ListView with checkboxes in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox, mvvm

I write a wpf application , using MVVM.
I have a ListView of products names with checkboxes (binding by ObservableCollection).

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding productsOfProject}" Margin="10">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn >
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <!--Command="{Binding CheckCommand}"-->
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}">
                                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProductCheck}"/>
                                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        </CheckBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding productName}" Header="Product Name" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Every product has an "IsChecked" property that updated according to the click.

I want to allow only one product to be marked.
At each check, I call a function that marks the current checked value as unmarked, but still in the UI , the check is not cleared.

```
#region Event
        public ICommand productCheck;
        public ICommand ProductCheck
        {
            get
            {
                if (productCheck == null)
                {
                    productCheck = new RelayCommand(p => productCheckFunc());
                }
                return productCheck;
            }
        }

        private void productCheckFunc()
        {
            uncheckedProducts();
        }
        private void uncheckedProducts()
        {
            foreach (Product p in rvm.productsOfProject)
            {
                if (p.id != this.id)
                    p.IsChecked = false;
            }
        }
        #endregion Event
```

How can I access to the List View and unchecked to current checked value ?

Comment: You should store the id of the last clicked product in your viewModel and have the CheckBox checked only if the id of the row is the same as the "CheckedProductId". This way you won't have to do all these checks.

Comment: FYI:  you don't want a "checkbox", you want "radio buttons".

Comment: I write the condition in the UI ? i have try to do something like that `<ListView.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding lastCheckedProductId}">
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.Resources>`

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved by using Radio Button instead of Combo Box.
In radio button selecting one value is the default, we will only need to set one group.

Solution :

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding productsOfProject}" Margin="10">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn >
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <RadioButton GroupName="One" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}">
                                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProductCheck}"/>
                                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        </RadioButton>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding productName}" Header="Product Name" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```